# Using shrink_to_fit() for releasing memory in vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management

Lets say I have `std::vector<std::vector<int>> a(n, std::vector<int>(n, x));`.
Now I want to release all the memory that `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` took. Is it enough to do

```
a.clear();
a.shrink_to_fit();
```

or should I do it for all internal vectors first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's enough to do it for the main one. For then, the inside-vector's destructor would be called, not just a resize to 0.

Doing it for all the inside-vectors - you are simply doing the compiler's job for him.

Also you can do it in one line:  `a = {};`

Comment: It's not the compilers job, but the destructors. And the destructor of the inner vectors will run anyway, even if the vectors are cleared before they are destroyed. And technically a resize to 0 (`a.resize(0)`) is the same as `a.clear()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just tested `a = {};`, looks like it doesn't release memory, because `a.capacity();` shows my `n`.

Comment: @АлексейБрагин it may be some optimization for debugging. It must certainly release memory.